# Difference between 2 internationalization (i18n) functions __() & _e()

Tags: translation, localization

I'm learning from a plugin development course, and encountered two different internationalization functions:

```
<?php __('Newsletter Subscriber', 'ns_domain'); ?>
```

&

```
<?php _e('Title:'); ?>
```

I cannot find any reference information on when to use each one of these.

Can you point me in the right direction to learn more about these please?

Comment: Just for the record, I edited the question replacing 'localization' with 'internationalization'. These are also abbreviated l10n and i18n respectively. Per the docs I linked in my answer "Localization describes the subsequent process of translating an internationalized plugin." Searching for `internationalization` would have yielded better results but localization and internationalization are easily mixed up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`__()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/_2) "Retrieves the translated string from the translate() function" without echoing. `_e()` does the same thing but echos the output.

For more information, take a look at these help articles:

- [Internationalization](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/internationalization/how-to-internationalize-your-plugin/)
- [Localization](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/internationalization/localization/)
- [**How to Internationalize Your Plugin**](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/internationalization/how-to-internationalize-your-plugin/)
- [Internationalization Security](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/internationalization/security/)

Answer (score 1):

It is probably good to know. The foundation of the internalization is the `translate` function

```
File: wp-includes/l10n.php
78: /**
79:  * Retrieve the translation of $text.
80:  *
81:  * If there is no translation, or the text domain isn't loaded, the original text is returned.
82:  *
83:  * *Note:* Don't use translate() directly, use __() or related functions.
84:  *
85:  * @since 2.2.0
86:  *
87:  * @param string $text   Text to translate.
88:  * @param string $domain Optional. Text domain. Unique identifier for retrieving translated strings.
89:  *                       Default 'default'.
90:  * @return string Translated text
91:  */
92: function translate( $text, $domain = 'default' ) {
```

Anytime you call any of the wrappers

```
File:wp-includes/l10n.php
172: function __( $text, $domain = 'default' ) {
173:    return translate( $text, $domain );
174: }
```

or

```
File: wp-includes/l10n.php
188: function esc_attr__( $text, $domain = 'default' ) {
189:    return esc_attr( translate( $text, $domain ) );
190: }
```

or

```
File: wp-includes/l10n.php
217: function _e( $text, $domain = 'default' ) {
218:    echo translate( $text, $domain );
219: }
```

or many other from `wp-includes/l10n.php`, this function will be called. But you never call this function directly.