# How to modify mobile nav menu text in theme

Tags: php, theme-development, menus, css, navigation

I'm using a child theme based on Theme Nectar's [Salient](http://themenectar.com/demo/salient-promo/) WordPress theme, and I'm encountering a frustrating issue in attempting to modify the text that displays for a sticky nav sub-menu in a collapsed (mobile) state. After digging through the parent theme files, I'm seeing that the php code responsible for the submenu, located in a "nectar-vc-addons" sub-folder, is as follows:

```
echo '<a href="#" class="mobile-menu-link"><i class="salient-page-submenu-icon"></i>'.__('Menu',NECTAR_THEME_NAME).'</a><ul  style="background-color:'.$bg_color.'; color: '.$link_color.';" >'.do_shortcode($content).'</ul>';
```

This results, in part, in the following markup being generated for the menu:

```
<a href="#" class="mobile-menu-link">
    <i class="salient-page-submenu-icon"></i>
    "Menu"
</a>
```

All I want to do is change this "Menu" text to something different, and there doesn't appear to be a theme option to do so; and I'd like to avoid altering the PHP in the theme file so it's not overwritten in the event of a theme version upgrade.

I realize I can use some jQuery trickery to alter the string, but I'm wondering if there's some way I can change the text in the `functions.php` file in my child theme or some other way? I'm open to CSS approaches as well perhaps using psuedo elements, but I can't come up with anything that works in changing the text within the anchor element and keeping the icon. Any assistance here is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can leverage the use of the `gettext` filter to change the text. Add this code to your child theme's `functions.php` or to a plugin:

```
add_filter('gettext', 'wpse248225_change_text', 20, 3 );
function wpse248225_change_text( $translated_text, $untranslated_text, $domain ) {
    if ( NECTAR_THEME_NAME !== $domain ) {
        return $translated_text;        
    }

    // Make the changes to the text
    switch( $untranslated_text ) {
            // Change 'Menu' text
            case 'Menu':
                $translated_text = __( 'something different', 'text_domain' );
            break;

            // add more items
     }

    return $translated_text;        
}
```

Comment: Wow, that is *exactly* what I was looking for, thank you, Dave! Works like a charm. One question-- why the name `wpse248225_change_text`?

Comment: Awesome, you got it! That is just a naming convention used here on WPSE so that functions have a unique name. It's just wpse_ + {question ID (from URL)}. You can safely replace that with your own prefix and replace `text_domain` with your own text domain string too.

Comment: Ah, got it-- makes sense; I will keep that in mind for the future on this forum! Last question-- what is the purpose of the `text_domain` portion?

Comment: That's just a unique identifier. Each plugin and theme should use its own unique text domain string. It allows for specific targeting of strings, such as in the example I posted. We just targeted the string `Menu` for the `NECTAR_THEME_NAME` text domain. (Side note, your parent theme is going against the guidelines by using a constant for the text domain; it should be a *string*.) More on translation stuff [here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/247712/2807).

Comment: Got it, thanks so much for the explanation, Dave. It's also not surprising that the parent theme is going against the guidelines-- I think it's crazy the "Menu" string is effectively hardcoded into the theme component this way in the first place.

Comment: Happy to help! Well, at least they used `__()`, it could have been worse :-)